# Swift xcode error "does not implement ...trouble ahead Unrecognized selector -[FinalProjectDavid.RowTable initWithCoder:]"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a "sign in" button which transports the user to a new window with a table of 12 rows but I get this error. The segue's identifier is `SignInButtonSecondSegue`.

Error in text form:

> 2016-03-07 16:48:10.119 FinalProjectDavid[4030:429084]  NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fb0895b3a40 of class 'FinalProjectDavid.RowTable' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector -[FinalProjectDavid.RowTable initWithCoder:]
>   (lldb)

Screenshot of error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUYG2.png)

Screenshot of the storyboard:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3PRi.png)

This is the login/signin button class that is attached to the login/sign in window/view.

```
import MessageUI
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Looks for single or multiple taps.

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }



    //Calls this function when the tap is recognized.

    func dismissKeyboard() {

        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.

        view.endEditing(true)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }





    @IBOutlet weak var ClickHereSendEmailButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var UsernameTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var PasswordTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var SignInButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func PressedSignInButton(sender: UIButton)
    {

        if UsernameTextField.text == username && PasswordTextField.text == password
        {

            performSegueWithIdentifier("SignInButtonSecondSegue", sender: nil) //this is where I get the error


            Label.text = "The credentials are correct."

            UsernameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

            PasswordTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        }
        else
        {

            // create the alert

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Incorrect", message: "Your credentials are incorrect.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)



            // add an action (button)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))



            // show the alert

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



            Label.text = "The credentials are not correct."

            UsernameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

            PasswordTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        }

    }



    @IBAction func PressedClickHereSendEmailButton(sender: UIButton)

    {

        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()

        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()

        }

    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {

        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()

        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property



        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["nurdin@gmail.com"])

        mailComposerVC.setSubject(" \(UsernameTextField.text), \(PasswordTextField.text)")//unwrap

        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)



        return mailComposerVC

    }



    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {

        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

        sendMailErrorAlert.show()

    }



    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate



    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

The rowtable class:

```
import UIKit



class RowTable
{

    init() // since it is overriding the NSObject init
    {

    }

    func viewDidLoad() {

       viewDidLoad()



        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations

        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false



        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.

        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    }



    func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

       didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections

        return 1

    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        return 12
    }

    func methodSingatureForSelector()
    {

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FileSlot", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        2

       let filename = rows[indexPath.row].FileName



        let button = UIButton(type: .System)



        button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)



       // self.view.addSubview(button)





        return cell

    }


    /*

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.

        return true

    }

    */



    /*

    // Override to support editing the table view.

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .Delete {

            // Delete the row from the data source

            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {

            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view

        }    

    }

    */



    /*

    // Override to support rearranging the table view.

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }

    */



    /*

    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.

        return true

    }

    */



    /*

    // MARK: - Navigation



    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.

        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    }

    */

}
```

The row class:

```
import UIKit


let rows = [

    Row(FileName: "File slot 1",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 1"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 2",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 2"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 3",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 3"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 4",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 4"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 5",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 5"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 6",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 6"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 7",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 7"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 8",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 8"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 9",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 9"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 10",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 10"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 11",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 11"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 12",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 12")]



class Row
{

    ///// enum Type: String {

    // }



    var FileName: String

    var QuartzImage: String



    // var type: Type

    // var shortDescription: String

    // var longDescription: String



    init(FileName: String, QuartzImage: String) {

        self.FileName = FileName

        self.QuartzImage = QuartzImage

    }

}
```

EDIT:Just added the row, and rowtable class, sorry about earlier not providing enough code/information.

Comment: If you want `RowTable` to be a table view controller subclass, you need to indicate that. `class RowTable : UITableViewController`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the error.